# Upload media like video and image with Websocket in swift

Tags: ios, swift, websocket, mobile-application

I am trying to upload and receive image and video media using WebSocket. Image and video are in base64 string format. I am getting an error while receiving the string from the server through socket "**Domain=kNWErrorDomainPOSIX Code=40 "Message too long" UserInfo={NSDescription=Message too long}**".

```
//MARK: Receive

func receiveMessage(){

 let workItem = DispatchWorkItem{ [weak self] in

  self?.webSocket?.receive(completionHandler: { result in
        
        switch result {
        case .success(let message):
            
            switch message {
            
            case .data(let data):
              //print("data")

            case .string(let strMessgae):
              //print("strMessgae")

       default:
                break
            }
        
        case .failure(let error):
            print("Error Receiving \(error)")
        }
      }
    }
```

Getting error in **case .failure**. Please help me out with the error and how to resolve it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

What I see is just a function of WebSocket that receives a Message.

```
case .data(let data):
```

In the data case, you will receive data (image, document, video)

```
case .string(let strMessgae):
 //print("strMessgae")
```

In strMessage, you will be receiving a text message (eg: hi, hello)

```
 public func sendData(data: String) {
    webSocket?.send(URLSessionWebSocketTask.Message.data(data.data(using: .utf8)!), completionHandler: { error in
        if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    })
}
```

try sending your image and video in the function above. Websocket has two functions to send message, either by Message or data.

Try this receive function:

```
public func receiveMessage() {
    webSocket?.receive(completionHandler: { [weak self] result in
        switch result {
        case .success(let message):
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                switch message {
                case .data(let data):
                    print("Data is \(data)")
                case .string(let text):
                   print("Receive Message \(text)")
                    
                @unknown default:
                    break
                }
            }
        case .failure(let error):
            print(error)
        }
        self?.receiveMessage()
    })
}
```

Comment: Hi Ahmed....thanks for your reply. But issue was not resolved, because of "self?.webSocket?.receive(completion handler: { result in }" this complition block throw me a failure error for "message is too long".

Comment: Your server would probably have restriction (limit). Try to change your server backend link. Make sure, you are sending image in data not in StrMessage. You can try piesocket link.

Comment: I am also doing the same task in Android and there it works fine. So I think there is no issue on the server side. And I don't set any restrictions at the server end also.

Comment: Could you edit your post and paste the string? let me try it out for you. Are you able to receive and send any other message apart from the image? Also, I have posted the receive function. Try that one

Comment: You can take any high-resolution image and can convert it into base64. Then upload it to the server.

Comment: yes I am able to send messages apart from the media.

Comment: base64 is a bad approach to send images because of a longstring. Why don't you just convert the image into data and send using websocket.send(data) function?